# Passing xml as applet param after upgrading JSF to 2.2

Tags: applet, xhtml, jsf-2.2

While working with JSF 2.1 I passed xml document string as java applet param. When I called getParameter in Java Applet, function returned whole document string. After upgrading JSF to 2.2. getParameter returns just prefix of document `<?xml version=`.

xhtml file:

```
<f:verbatim>
    <object type="application/x-java-applet" width="300" height="300">
         <param name="archive" value="#{someBean.appletUrl}" />
         <param name="code" value="somePackage.someClass" />
         <param name="permissions" value="all-permissions" />
         <param name="xmlParam" value="#{someBean.xmlParam}" />
    </object>
</f:verbatim>
```

Function getXmlParam returns string with not escaped, valid xml document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"><someTag someAttribute="attrValue"> someValue </someTag>
```

Rendered html while using JSF 2.1:

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" width="300" height="300">
    <param name="archive" value="http://someURL/applet.jar">
    <param name="code" value="somePackage.someClass">
    <param name="permissions" value="all-permissions">
    <param name="xmlParam" value="<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"><someTag someAttribute="attrValue">someValue</someTag>">
</object>
```

Rendered html after upgrade to JSF 2.2:

```
<object type="application/x-java-applet" width="300" height="300">
    <param name="archive" value="http://someURL/applet.jar">
    <param name="code" value="somePackage.someClass">
    <param name="permissions" value="all-permissions">
    <param name="xmlParam" value="<?xml version=" 1.0"="" encoding="UTF-8" ?&gt;="" &lt;someTag="" someAttribute="attrValue" &gt;="" someValue ="" sometag&gt;"="">
</object>
```

As I see problem must be connected with change of method of escaping quotation inside string pasted to html in JSF 2.2. Does anybody have idea how to pass xml document as applet param in JSF 2.2 in elegant way (without manually encoding in bean and decoding in applet)?

Answer (score 0):

you can sen a url about the archive of xml, first write that archive in some place, in the applet connect to url and write the archive